# How to link SUMO to Webots?

Tags: simulation, sumo, webots

I am currently working on a project that involves simulating urban traffic using both SUMO and Webots. I want to integrate these two simulations to have a comprehensive traffic simulation environment. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to link SUMO with Webots. I've researched the documentation for both tools, but I'm looking for practical guidance and best practices.
Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on occlusion detection in self driving cars. so I want to use webots and sumo. firstly I have design world for simulation. Now i want to link it with sumo.